# spring cloud sleuth - new propagation field which joins span-ids

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth

I would like to add a new custom propagation field - Request-Id.

This new field should be a sum of span-ids separated by dots. For example if we have such a chain of calls:

```
(ServiceA) -----> (ServiceB) -----> (ServiceC) -----> (ServiceD)
```

Span Ids are ("**SpanAB**", "**SpanBC**", "**SpanCD**") respectively.
Request-ids should be ("**SpanAB**", "**SpanAB.SpanBC**", "**SpanAB.SpanBC.SpanCD**") respectively.

Could you help me with creating this new custom field?

Comment: I added new filter which is executed after sleuth's TracingFilter. My filter uses spanId generated by sleuth TracingFilter, and adds/modifies baggage (i.e. it creates new baggage or add spanId at the end of existing baggate)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the docs, you should be able to implement this using a [`Baggage`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features-baggage).

Fyi: Sleuth is using Brave's [`Baggage`](https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/tree/master/brave#baggage) under the hood by default.